# set env var in Python multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, environment-variables, multiprocessing

In the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) Python 2 module, [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) can be given an `env`.

Seems that the equivalent way to do it with [Process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module is to pass the `env` dictionnary in `args` or `kwargs`, and then use `os.environ['FOO'] = value` in the `target`.

Is it the right way?

Is it safe? I mean, no risk that the environment in the parent process or other child processes can be modified?

Here is an example (that works).

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

def target(someid):
    os.environ['FOO'] = "foo%i" % someid
    for i in range(10):
        print "Job %i: " % someid, os.environ['FOO']
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    processes = []

    os.environ['FOO'] = 'foo'

    for someid in range(3):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=(someid,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    for i in range(10):
        print "Parent: ", os.environ['FOO']
        time.sleep(1)

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 33):

Yes, that's the right way to do it. While the child will inherit its initial environment from the parent, subsequent changes to `os.environ` made in the child will not affect the parent, and vice-versa:

```
import os
import multiprocessing


def myfunc(q):
    print "child: " + os.environ['FOO']
    os.environ['FOO'] = "child_set"
    print "child new: " + os.environ['FOO']
    q.put(None)
    q.get()
    print "child new2: " + os.environ['FOO']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['FOO'] = 'parent_set'
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunc, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    q.get()
    print "parent: " + os.environ['FOO']
    os.environ['FOO'] = "parent_set_again"
    q.put(None)
```

Output:

```
child start: parent_set
child after changing: child_set
parent after child changing: parent_set
child after parent changing: child_set
```

If you need to pass an initial environment to the child, you would just pass it in the `args` or `kwargs` list:

```
def myfunc(env=None):
    time.sleep(3)
    if env is not None:
        os.environ = env
    print os.environ['FOO']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_env = os.environ.copy()

    for i in range(3):
        child_env['FOO'] = "foo%s" % (i,)
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunc, kwargs ={'env' : child_env})
        proc.start()
```

Output:

```
foo0
foo1
foo2
```

Note that if you're using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, you can use the `initializer`/`initargs` keyword arguments to just set the correct environment once at the start of each process in the pool:

```
def init(env):
    os.environ = env

def myfunc():
    print os.environ['FOO']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_env = os.environ.copy()
    child_env['FOO'] = "foo"
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(child_env,))
    pool.apply(myfunc,())
```

Output:

```
foo
```