# Prevent creating new child process using subprocess in Python

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, parent-child, popen

I need to run a lot of bash commands from Python. For the moment I'm doing this with
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)

Is there any solution to run all these commands in the same shell? subprocess.Popen opens a new shell at every execution and I need to set up all the necessary variables at every call, in order for cmd command to work properly.

Comment: Each command you run is still a subprocess, and a child process of either your script or the shell that was spawned by your script. Do you need the shell between your child and your script?

Comment: At every subprocess.Popen I need to export a variable and to run cmd command in the same call. This will generate an ugly syntax. It will be great to export that variable only once and, after this, to run my cmd commands.

Comment: Unless you actually need to use `subprocess.Popen()`, you should use `multiprocessing.Process` instead. (Are all your jobs independent and unsychronized? Do you need to worry about catching nonzero error status in the middle of your sequence of jobs?)

Comment: OP, you should actually tell us what "a lot of bash commands" are. If they're executables, invoke the executable already, with multiprocessing; if they're bash builtins, then you don't need to thunk out to bash to do this. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Not all the jobs are independent and unsynchronized. Yes, I need to  stop the entire process if some nonzero values appear.

Comment: All my commands call an executable file with different arguments.

Comment: OP, I asked you what bash commands? **date? chmod? cd? <some executable>?**

Comment: You have presented zero reason why you don't just call the executable directly (e.g. with `multiprocessing`). Catch the exit status (and the stdout if you need to).

Comment: @smci, eh? `multiprocessing` is specifically for when the subprocess is also Python, which very much sounds not to be the case here. If you want to use a subprocess with no shell, the `subprocess` module is fine for that -- just don't ever use `shell=True` or pass `cmd` as a string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead, it's more lightweight and efficient.

Unlike subprocess.Popen it does not open a new shell at every execution.

You didn't say you *need* to run `subprocess.Popen` and you may well not need to; you just said that's what you're currently doing. More justification please.

See [set env var in Python multiprocessing.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642811/set-env-var-in-python-multiprocessing-process) for how to set your env vars once and for all in the parent process.

Comment: Can you explain how `multiprocessing` would actually be helpful here?

Comment: Because unlike subprocess.Popen it does not open a new shell at every execution, which is what the OP complained about. Have you considered not downvoting correct answers? It's vexatious and destructive.

Comment: I didn't downvote. `subprocess.Popen` executes a child process. `multiprocessing.Process` executes a python callable (like a function) in another process. How would you use `multiprocessing.Process` to execute a bunch of bash commands in a single shell, like the OP wants?

Comment: If the OP wants to call executables, then just call the executable. The OP didn't say they *need* to run `subprocess.Popen`. They just said that's what they're currently doing.

Comment: @dano: if you actually read the OP's question and dig at its intent, nowhere did they say they *need* to execute a bunch of bash commands in a single shell. And it turns out they didn't need to - just call an executable (not a bash builtin) several times, with different args. Less bickering, more insight.

Comment: You can't use `multiprocessing`'s APIs to call arbitrary executables. You use it to run a Python function in a child process. It's designed to be a drop-in replacement for the `threading` module. If the OP was using `subprocess` to run Python scripts written specifically for use in this application, then using `multiprocessing` definitely makes sense. But the OP hasn't stated that anywhere. He/she did accept this answer, so maybe that was actually what they were doing. But for any other use-case where you'd use `subprocess`, it doesn't make sense to use `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @smci, the claim that `subprocess.Popen()` opens a new shell at every execution is wrong. It only does this when used with `shell=True`, or with a string passed for `cmd`.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.Popen` lets you supply a dictionary of environment variables, which will become the environment for the process being run. If the only reason you need `shell=True` is to set an environment variable, then I suggest you use an explicit environment dictionary instead;  it's safer and not particularly difficult. Also, it's usually much easier to construct command invocations when you don't have to worry about quoting and shell metacharacters.

It may not even be necessary to construct the environment dictionary, if you don't mind having the environment variables set in the running process. (Most of the time, this won't be a problem, but sometimes it is. I don't know enough about your application to tell.)

If you can modify your own environment with the settings, just do that:

```
os.environ['theEnvVar'] = '/the/value'
```

Then you can just use a simple `Popen.call` (or similar) to run the command:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-lR", "/tmp"])
```

If for whatever reason you cannot change your own environment, you need to make a copy of the current environment, modify it as desired, and pass it to each `subprocess.call`:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['theEnvVar'] = '/the/value'
output = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-lR", "/tmp"], env=env)
```

If you don't want to have to specify `env=env` every time, just write a little wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a shell script with all the commands you need to run, then just use a single `subprocess.Popen()` call to run it? If the contents of the commands you need to run depend on results calculated in your Python script, you can just create the shell script dynamically, then run it.

Comment: My commands are separated by others python operations. I don't know how this can be done, but I suppose that it will result a complex syntax.

Comment: Having only one shell is still worse than zero shells. I don't see any reason given why we can't have zero shells -- invoking each command with an explicit argv array and thus (implicitly) `shell=False`.